# How do I get selected value of dropdown list in javascript?? (without selected attribute)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to get the selected option of a dropdown list to display a second question accordingly. So, if my code is

```
<form>
      <label for="stall">Choose a stall: </label>
      <select name="stall" id="stall">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="Stall 1: Drinks">Stall 1: Drinks</option>
        <option value="Stall 2: Mama Baked Rice">Stall 2: Mama Baked Rice</option>
        <option value="Stall 3: Mixed Veg Rice">Stall 3: Mixed Veg Rice</option>
        <option value="Stall 4: Noodles">Stall 4: Noodles</option>
        <option value="Stall 5: Korean and Jap">Stall 5: Korean and Jap</option>
        <option value="Stall 6: Western">Stall 6: Western</option>
        <option value="Stall 7: Mama Pasta">Stall 7: Mama Pasta</option>
        <option value="Stall 8: Muslim">Stall 8: Muslim</option>
      </select>
  </form>
```

and would like to display second question (menu) based on the stall chosen, how do I do that using javascript?

Comment: So you don't want to use `element.value` or `element.selectedIndex` or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply attach the event (*change*) and inside the event handler function capture the the *value* like the following way:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#stall');
el.addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<form>
      <label for="stall">Choose a stall: </label>
      <select name="stall" id="stall">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="Stall 1: Drinks">Stall 1: Drinks</option>
        <option value="Stall 2: Mama Baked Rice">Stall 2: Mama Baked Rice</option>
        <option value="Stall 3: Mixed Veg Rice">Stall 3: Mixed Veg Rice</option>
        <option value="Stall 4: Noodles">Stall 4: Noodles</option>
        <option value="Stall 5: Korean and Jap">Stall 5: Korean and Jap</option>
        <option value="Stall 6: Western">Stall 6: Western</option>
        <option value="Stall 7: Mama Pasta">Stall 7: Mama Pasta</option>
        <option value="Stall 8: Muslim">Stall 8: Muslim</option>
      </select>
  </form>
```

Comment: there's a error message saying addEventListener cannot read null properties. which property is null?

Comment: @salted-caramel, check the *id* used in the element and in your code, the error indicates there is mismatch between them.